# Redux-saga upload file progress event

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am using redux-saga to upload files and I am trying to figure a way to dispatch an event whenever the upload progress changes:

```
const data = new FormData();

data.append('file', fileWrapper.file);

const uploadedFile = yield call(request, requestURL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  },
  body: data
});
```

Any idea how to attach an upload progress event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the answer depends on how do you do uploadRequest.

It seems like you are using [window.fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API. This API doesn't provide you a way to receive upload progress events.

So, you need to switch to use `XMLHttpRequest` or a library that wraps it in a convenient way for you. I'd recommend you to look at [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) and [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent). They both provide a way to listen to progress events.

The next topic is to how to dispatch progress actions in `redux-saga`. You need to use `fork` to create a forked async tasks and dispatch actions there.

```
function uploadEmitter(action) {
  return eventChannel(emit => {
     superagent
       .post('/api/file')
       .send(action.data)
       .on('progress', function(e) {
           emit(e);
       });
  });
}

function* progressListener(chan) {
  while (true) {
    const data = yield take(chan)
    yield put({ type: 'PROGRESS', payload: data })
  }
}

function* uploadSaga(action) {
  const emitter = uploadEmitter()
  yield fork(progressListener, emitter)
  const result = yield call(identity(promise))
  yield put({ type: 'SUCCESS', payload: result })
}
```

Source: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/613#issuecomment-258384017

**P.S.** in my personal opinion, redux-saga is not an appropriate tool to implement such kind of functionality. Would be much cleaner to do this with `redux-thunk`:

```
function uploadAction(file) {
  return dispatch => {
    superagent
      .post('/api/file')
      .send(action.data)
      .on('progress', function(event) {
           dispatch({type: 'UPLOAD_PROGRESS', event});
      })
      .end(function(res) {
           if(res.ok) {
              dispatch({type: 'UPLOAD_SUCCESS', res});
           } else {
              dispatch({type: 'UPLOAD_FAILURE', res});
           }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: nice solution. Can you elaborate on where do the `identity` and `promise` come from in `yield call(identity(promise))` line? Thanks!

Comment: I just last week was thinking what a great idea it would be to create an uploader using redux and redux-saga. So i decided to create a library for it - https://github.com/el-davo/react-typescript-upload-saga

Comment: Nik So, check code at https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/613#issuecomment-258384017